# DateTime ParseExact not working when changing time

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

I'm having trouble figuring out why my date is parsed correctly until I change the time of the date passed into the parse method.

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-02-05T07:00:00+00:00", "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dateValueToTryParse = parsedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The required result is outputted and I do get `05/02/2016`. However, if I change the string passed in to:

```
2016-02-19T23:59:00+00:00
```

The output of `dateValueToTryParse` remains the same and it is not parsed correctly. Am I doing anything particularly wrong with my parsing? I'm confused as the format seems to be exactly the same?

Comment: are you sure you re-compiled before you re-ran the code?

Comment: There are many questions about "I did not read [custom date time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), but why my string does not parse day/month/hour correctly". I'm not sure if every version needs its own question, so voting to close as "typographical error" (if disagree please consider finding good duplicate instead of providing yet another one use "HH" instead of "hh".

Comment: Makes sense. My fault for not reading the documentation properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your incoming format to `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00`.

The difference is `HH`. Capital H means 24 hour clock or "military time".

Otherwise, it is trying to parse hour 23 which doesn't exist.

See here for more detailed information on other formats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I guess it's my mistake for not reading the documentation properly. Thank you very much for pointing it. Will be sure to check it properly first before posting more questions :) Thanks for your time

Comment: @Chongman Oh no bro, this wasn't a RTFM thing. Just passing it along.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `hh` to `HH` specifier *can* solve your problem but since your string has an [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, I would prefer to parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) instead of `DateTime` for *consistency*.

```
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2016-02-05T23:00:00+00:00", 
                                    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now, you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{05.02.2016 23:00:00 +00:00}` and you can use it's [`.DateTime` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime) to get the `DateTime` value represented by it.

```
var dateValueToTryParse = dto.DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will generate `05/02/2016` as a result.